# Matplotlib image update issue under _thread

Tags: python, matplotlib

System

Raspbian

Issue description

Image cannot update under _thread module. The img_1 can always be shown. The img_2 can be update without _thread apllication.
But the img_2 cannot be update if I applied _thread.
Need help!

Code example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import time
import _thread


def PTest():
    img_1 = Image.open("/home/pi/development/content/P1.jpg")
    img_2 = Image.open("/home/pi/development/content/P2.jpg")

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ax.imshow(img_1)
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()

    time.sleep(5)
    ax.imshow(img_2)


# PTest()

try:
    _thread.start_new_thread(PTest, ())
except:
    print("thread error")
```

Comment: Can you post the error message you get?

Comment: There is no error message. The code can run smoothly. The image can be update if I remove last four lines of code and run PTest() directly.